# How to solve this integral equation?

Tags: calculus, integral-equations

Solve this integral equation:
$$
{{\rm e}^{{\rm i}k\,\sqrt{\vphantom{\Large A}\,r^{2} + z^{2}\,}\,}
\over
\sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}r^{2} + z^{2}\,}}
=
\int_0^{\infty}{\rm K}_{0}\left(\lambda r\right)
\cos\left(\,\sqrt{\vphantom{\Large A}\,\lambda^{2} + k^{2}\,}\,z\right)
{\rm f}\left(\lambda\right)\,{\rm d}\lambda
$$

where ${\rm f}\left(\lambda\right)$ is the unknown function.
${\rm K}_{0}\left(\lambda r\right)$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind of order zero. $r > 0$.

Could anyone give some hints ?. Thanks !.

Comment: Where did you find this monster?

Comment: Just from the dipole radiation theory introduced by Arnold Sommerfeld. The LHS of the above equation is the Hertz vector. I wonder is there an alternative expression to the one given by Sommerfeld(It's given by Bessel function $J_0(\lambda r))$. In fact I just change the sign of the arbitrary constant while solving the Helmholtz equation.

Comment: Yes, and then use Mellin transform. Thanks.

Comment: You can set $\displaystyle\large k \to k\left\vert\,z\,\right\vert\,,\quad r \to {r \over \left\vert\,z\,\right\vert}$, etc... and redefine $\displaystyle\large{\rm f}$.

Comment: maybe it works, but it seems convenient to set $z=0$ to eliminate the cosine factor in the integral equation.

Comment: The problem is solved. The answer is $$f(\lambda)=\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda^2+k^2}}$$ and the integration path must be changed to W:{-ik}\to\infty. W is deformable in the complex plane.